# Winlogon Notification DLL -- Create Process as the user who logged in

Tags: c++, dll, notify, winlogon

I have a requirement to run an app as a user unlocks his computer. This works swimmingly in Win 7 with regular task scheduler. For XP -- ive Created a C++ DLL to do this. This seems to work great, except that it does so under the system account (and thus doesnt show up ont he user's desktop).

I have 2 functions, the first WLEventLogon launches the process under the system acct,

The 2nd, (I havent done C++ in like 15 years so Im a tad rusty!) is most likely wildly incorrect. I'm trying to get a simple app to run on the user's account whenever he unlocks the system.

Below is my code -- the dll works and Ive tested the methods with rundll32 and using them in winlogon/notify

```
    // Here is the event handler for the Winlogon Logon event.
//__declspec( dllexport ) void WLEventLogon (PWLX_NOTIFICATION_INFO pInfo);

WINLOGINDLL_API void WLEventLogon (PWLX_NOTIFICATION_INFO pInfo)
{   

    const wchar_t* path =  L"C:\\path\\app.exe";


    ShellExecute(GetDesktopWindow(),L"open",path,NULL,NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);      
}


WINLOGINDLL_API void Test (PWLX_NOTIFICATION_INFO pInfo)
{   


STARTUPINFOW        lpStartupInfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInfo;

ZeroMemory(&lpStartupInfo, sizeof(lpStartupInfo));
ZeroMemory(&lpProcessInfo, sizeof(lpProcessInfo));
lpStartupInfo.cb = sizeof(lpStartupInfo);
lpStartupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
lpStartupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW;
CreateProcessAsUser(pInfo->hToken, L"C:\\path\\app.exe",L"test",NULL,NULL,FALSE,NULL,NULL,NULL,&lpStartupInfo,&lpProcessInfo);

   }
```

The 'test' function doesnt seem to be working at all -- My CreateProcessAsUser is most likely wildly wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you make sure the `hToken` value is not NULL?  If it is not, try using `DuplicateTokenEx()` to retreive the user's primary token, then pass that to `CreateProcessAsUser()`.

```
WINLOGINDLL_API void Test (PWLX_NOTIFICATION_INFO pInfo)
{
    if( !pInfo->hToken )
        return;

    STARTUPINFOW        lpStartupInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInfo;
    ZeroMemory(&lpStartupInfo, sizeof(lpStartupInfo));
    ZeroMemory(&lpProcessInfo, sizeof(lpProcessInfo));
    lpStartupInfo.cb = sizeof(lpStartupInfo);
    lpStartupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    lpStartupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW;

    HANDLE hUserToken;
    if( !DuplicateTokenEx(pInfo->hToken, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, NULL, SecurityIdentification, TokenPrimary, &hToken) )
        return;

    if( CreateProcessAsUser(hUserToken, ...) )
    {
        ...
    }

    CloseHandle(hUserToken);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `Impersonate` value set to 1 in the registration of the notification dll. (see [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379402%28VS.85%29.aspx)). It will make impersonation of the user.

I personally always prefer to set explicitly `"WinSta0\\Default"` as `lpDesktop` field of the `STARTUPINFOW` and use `CreateProcess` API instead of `ShellExecute`.

Moreover it is a little strange that the name of the function `WLEventLogon` and not something like `WLEventLogon`. Do you register the function name as `Unlock` value in the registry?